# streaming and downloading flashed on mobile

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I would like to make my flash file working on adobe air to be streamed online and while it is streaming, it is downloaded for further calls to be working offline, any body can guide in this?

•   If the file is on the mobile device it will work

•   If the file is not on the mobile device, it will be streamed to work and downloaded to the mobile memory to be working offline when it is called later.

Comment: What kind of file do you want to be streamed? Are you talking about a video / audio file?

Comment: They are interactive flash files, these files contain videos, animation or quizzes. The current situation is that if I added the files to apk for example it works fine but sometimes the files are too large and the apk be more than 100 MB and I don't want to make my user to download all of that, I just want my user to download what he/she want and don't want them to be online all the time they are using my app